# How to set a Path to run Gitea commands in Terminal regardless on the directory?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gogs, gitea

After installing Gitea from binary, I can only run the Gitea commands from the gitea home dir with eg. `./gitea -v`

How do I set a Path so that Terminal responds to Gitea commands? The server is up and running and have created accounts etc.

Does a Path need to be added somehow to the `.bashrc` file?

The answer should enable "gitea" to be typed in Terminal as a command anywhere not just in the home Gitea folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use `export` in your `.bashrc`?

```
export PATH=$PATH:/my/path/to/gitea
```

By adding `$PATH` in the export, it appends the path `gitea` path rather than overwriting the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: oh love you! Perfect Thank you so much. No rep to upvote but will come back for you.